# Integration between issue tracker and version control

Tags: version-control, bug-tracking

I guess the proper integration should allow easily associate commits with tracked issues. For example, one can do it by prompting a committer changes with issues assigned to him. Is it the only example of such integration?

Comment: What is your question? This sounds more like a discussion.

Comment: Ok, the question is what are the patterns of integration b/w bug tracking and version control s/w.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a branch capable system (I mean Git, Hg and so on) you can do ["branch per task"](http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2010/08/branch-per-task-workflow-explained.html)  which is pretty powerful and then associate the branch to the task/issue directly.